# Delete permissions on Windows

Tags: windows, permissions

We want to be able to allow a user to delete an executable (during a re-install) but not execute it (forces them to use a less privilaged account for day to day operations). Is this possible using standard Windows file permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
You need to use the advanced permission editor (by clicking "advanced" in the standard permission window) and grant your user only the "delete" permission.